# VS Code: Error while installing 'C/C++' extension. Please check the log for more details

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

While downloading any extension, I am having above error. I uninstalled the vs-code and installed it again, but the same problem occurs. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked the log?  You could also provide it.

Comment: Try to download the actual VSIX package from Microsoft Marketplace and then install it directly. That might work for you, or at least reveal more about the installation error.

Comment: I have tried to install VSIX package directly. Didn't work

Comment: Can you try running VSCode as Admin?

Answer (score 4):

you can add extension via terminal. here are the steps to install the GCC compiler on Ubuntu:

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt install build-essential` the command installs a bunch of new packages including gcc, g++ and make.
3. to check the version type the command `gcc --version`

Answer (score 2):

Running as admin worked for me after experiencing the same issue.